# How to create the order programatically in magento2

Tags: magento2, orders, magento2.2, sales-order, programmatically

How to create the order programmatically in magento2 using objectManager. I need to test the order creating or not in the root folder. 
Can you please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you to create order.

https://webkul.com/blog/create-quote-and-order-programmatically-in-magento2/

Comment: The order items were not taken properly. It takes only the last item from item’s array.